# How do I return the count of each relationship type from apoc.path.subgraphall in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm working with the basic data set that neo4j provides from the `:play movies` command.

I am attempting to first find the subgraph that a specific nodes is connected to, which I do with this call:

`MATCH (movie:Movie) WHERE movie.title = "Cloud Atlas"
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(movie, {}) YIELD nodes, relationships 
RETURN nodes, relationships;`

This returns all of the nodes and the relationships in this particular graph, which is fine. **But I am looking for a way to get the count of each specific relationship type in the graph that is returned**.

In the top bar, these numbers are already displayed. ie:
**REVIEWED(9), PRODUCED(15), WROTE(10), etc.**

How would I get these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return each relationship type and a count for that type:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie) WHERE movie.title = "Cloud Atlas"
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(movie, {}) YIELD relationships 
UNWIND relationships AS r
RETURN TYPE(r) AS type_r, COUNT(*) AS num
```